# CloudKit: Query predicate list against array

Tags: nspredicate, cloudkit, predicate

I'm looking to construct a predicate which checks if a list of strings in CloudKit contains any element in an array of strings. I know I can check if a string is in a list in CloudKit by using the `CONTAINS` predicate, and I also know I can check if a string field is in an array using the `IN` predicate, however due to using an array/list of strings on both sides of the predicate I need form a `CONTAINS IN` predicate. anyone know how?

Comment: Does `ANY array IN otherArray` work?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ANY array IN otherArray` within the predicate